# Cisco ASA logs "regular translation creation failed for icmp" for client DNS traffic

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I am having an issue similar to [Cisco ASA logs "regular translation creation failed for icmp …" for DNS traffic, yet it works](https://serverfault.com/questions/126311/cisco-asa-logs-regular-translation-creation-failed-for-icmp-for-dns-traffic) however in my situation the source is a MacBook Pro (10.7) not running BIND.

Every few minutes my ASA logs the following message yet DNS resolution is working fine:

`%ASA-3-305006: regular translation creation failed for icmp src inside:172.16.0.180 dst outside:8.8.8.8 (type 3, code 3)`

Is there anything to be concerned about this message?  Is there a way to prevent this message without disabling event 305006 entirely?

Answer (score 1):

172.16.0.180 is generating an ICMP `Port Unreachable` message, and trying to send it to 8.8.8.8.

This is essentially the same issue as seen in that other question, while in completely different circumstances; the system (in the case, a DNS client instead of server) gets data that it wasn't waiting for for whatever reason and responds with an `Port Unreachable` packet.

There's nothing to worry about with regard to functionality as long as your DNS resolution is functioning properly, but getting rid of the logs is a little more iffy.  You could potentially have your ASA play DNS forwarder instead of having the client system directly hit the google revolvers.. or just disable the logs.